Prove that convex combinations of product states admit a hidden variable model
Define product states as simple tensors $\rho_1 \otimes \rho_2$ and separable states to be (trace) norm limits of convex combinations of product states. We say that a state $\rho$ admits a hidden variable model if there is a probability space $(X,\Sigma,\mu)$ such that given two observables with spectral decomposition $A=\sum_n \alpha_n P_n, B=\sum_m \beta_m Q_m$ one can find the so called response functions $x \mapsto F_A(n|x),x \mapsto F_B(m|x)$ such that
$$\operatorname{tr}((P_n \otimes Q_m)\rho)=\int_X F_A(n|x)F_B(m|x)d \mu(x) $$
(one assumes that these functions are measurable, positive and sum up to $1$).
It is easy to see that if $\rho=\sum_{r=1}^N p_r S_r \otimes T_r$ where $p_r \geq 0, \sum_{r=1}^N p_r=1$ then one can construct hidden variable model: just take $X:=\{1,2,...,N\}$ with $\mu(\{r\})=p_r$ and $F_A(n|r)=\operatorname{tr}(P_n S_r)$ and $F_B(m|r)=\operatorname{tr}(Q_m T_r)$.

How to prove that if $\rho$ is a (trace norm) limit of convex combinations of product states then $\rho$ also admits hidden variable model?

In particular I'm not sure about a general form of a separable state: I believe that it is not the case that any such state is of the form $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty} p_r S_r \otimes T_r$ where $\sum_{r=1}^{\infty}p_r=1$ and one shuld not confuse a decomposition into product states with the decomposition into pure states.

what's the point of bringing the observables $A,B$ into it? Their eigenvalues don't matter, so in practice the question is only a function of the pair of projective measurements $(P_n)_n$ and $(Q_m)_m$. That aside, I'm not sure I understand the final question. Separable states are by definition convex combinations of (not necessarily pure) product states. What other definition are you going by?

Thanks, only the spectral decomposition enter into the formula so the observables are not entirely relevant. Regarding separability: I have defined separable states to be limits of convex combinations of product states: I don't see why any such limit should again be convex combination of product states.

ah, I see. In which case, https://mathoverflow.net/q/332478/84108 is probably relevant

Thank you, this discussion is very interesting and nontrivial: I suspect that the proof that any separable state admits hidden variable model should be easier but I don't see how to construct the apriopriate probabilistic space.

One straighforward way to proceed is to show that the set of states admitting hidden variable model is closed-but I don't whether this statement is true...
